# using jquery, what is the easiest way to disable and enable a section of html input controls

Tags: jquery, forms

i have a bunch of form inputs (textboxex, radio buttons, checkboxes, etc)

there is a specific section of the form that i want to enable and disable.

i want a quick way when i click on a radio button (which is not part of the form) to disable all inputs in this specific section of a form. also on the selection of a different radio button (also not on the form in question) to enable that same section of the form input controls.

**The one trick is that i dont fully have control over the id and classes of the actual inputs so i need something where i can put a parent div and have it find all items within that div**

is there an easy way in jquery to enable or disable a section of input controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which grabs all inputs, textareas, selects and buttons, providing a context to [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) will limit this to inputs inside a parent, then [change the `disabled` attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
 $(':input', parent).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Removing the disabled attribute will re-enable:

```
 $(':input', parent).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Agreed! I've been doing too much Dojo recently. -.-

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a div by adding the "disabled" attribute like this:

```
$('div.container').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

You can then re-enable it by removing the attribute:

```
$('.someElement').removeAttr('disabled');
```

In your case, add a click handler to your radio button or other control which uses the above lines of code to enable/disable the div element (and, by extension, all of its content), like this (for disabling):

```
$('#radio-button1').click(function() {
    $('div.container').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$('#your_div_name').find('input').disable();

Needs [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/disable).

Answer (score -1):

The first way I can think of to do this is to insert/remove the word "disabled" into the inputs you want to manipulate.  You could do this with the appendTo() or html() functions selecting all inputs which match a certain id/class name.